# Where do I change my shell?

Tags: shell

If I wanted to use `zsh`, for instance, rather than `bash`, where would I make this change for the current user?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Chris Browne's answer works well if you don't have access to the user and have root privileges.

If you want to change the default shell of your current user you can also use:

```
chsh -s /bin/ksh
```

**More info**

The login shell of a user is defined in a file (`/etc/passwd` on Debian). This files has an entry for each user with the info entered at creation.

```
rahmu:x:1000:1000:My Nameisrahmu,,,:/home/rahmu:/bin/bash
anotheruser:x:1001:1001:,,,:/home/anotheruser:/bin/ksh
```

The last column is the login shell. It will be forked by the login program if successful.

However it is highly recommended that you do not modify this file by hand. You should use `chsh` or `usermod` whenever possible.

Comment: Need to make sure that /bin/zsh is listed in /etc/shells.

Comment: re: "on debian" is there a unix where this isn't true?

Comment: I just checked on the Solaris server at work. File `/etc/passwd` has only 19 entries. I know for a fact there are a lot more users on the system that that.

Answer (score 43):

`usermod -s /bin/zsh <username>`

See `man usermod` for more options.

Comment: Right, it's not set in a config, file, rather it's a user-definition level thing. Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to run this through `sudo`.  The `usermod` command is unprivileged unlike chsh.

Comment: This is very true, and there is in fact a third way of doing it, which is to add the command "/bin/zsh" to the end of your .bash_rc.  I believe rahmu's answer more accurately answers this question, my answer answers the more generalised "how do I change a user's shell?" question - which is more of a sysadmin's question, and less of a user's question, which is why I assumed that was the question being asked.

Answer (score 5):

You can change your login shell with the `chsh` command. As `man chsh` notes, a normal user can only change the shell for their own account, while root can change the shell for all accounts.

`/etc/shells` contains the pathnames of valid login shells. This file is queried by `chsh` when it is invoked.

The instructions for using `chsh` vary according to your UNIX flavour:

**Linux:**

```
chsh -s newshell
```

**Solaris:**

```
chsh newshell
```

**HP-UX**

```
chsh username newshell
```

**AIX**

```
chsh
```

This will start an interactive session where you are prompted for the full path to your new shell.

Reference: http://kb.iu.edu/data/benf.html

Answer (score 2):

On systems where you don't have sudo access or proper permission to use chsh (for example if you cannot add /bin/zsh to /etc/shell), then you can do it the old fashioned way:

```
$ mv ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_profile.old
$ (echo :; echo exec /bin/zsh -il) > ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

This will replace the `bash` shell with a login `zsh` at login.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do this on a Synology device running DSM 5.1 with ash shell running.  For some reason the `chsh` command was not available.  I had to instead edit the file `/etc/passwd`, putting in the full path to the shell executable I instead wanted.