# How to change default shell to ZSH - chsh says "invalid shell"

Tags: shell, zsh, users, login

I installed ZSH on a VM of mine, where I compiled it from source. The location of ZSH is `/usr/local/bin/zsh` when I run `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/zsh` it outputs `chsh: /usr/local/bin/zsh is an invalid shell`. I also tried this with sudo as well. How can I change this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where do I change my shell?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22729/where-do-i-change-my-shell)

Comment: @Mikel, no, that question is "I don't know about `chsh`" rather than "`chsh` isn't working for me".

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Add zsh to `/etc/shells`:

```
command -v zsh | sudo tee -a /etc/shells
```

You can now use chsh to set zsh as shell:

```
sudo chsh -s "$(command -v zsh)" "${USER}"
```

See this documentation: [Changing your login shell](https://web.archive.org/web/20170911211048/https://debian-administration.org/article/231/Changing_your_login_shell)

Comment: Word of warning: /ec/shells is not always created by default. If you use the above command, it will be created with ONLY zsh. Users with other shells, including the default bash shell, will NOT be able to login to the system. Spent 45 minutes pulling my hair out trying to figure out why I couldn't log into the system as root or any other user, even after booting from USB drive and repeatedly resetting passwords.

Answer (score 9):

You need to add `/usr/local/bin/zsh` to `/etc/shells`.

Answer (score 7):

First, check if `zsh` is listed as a valid shell by

```
cat /etc/shells
```

If `zsh` is not listed, install it. For example, if you use `apt`

```
sudo apt-get install zsh
```

Do, step 1 again and see the path of `zsh`. In my case, both `/usr/bin/zsh` and `/usr/zsh` is listed. 
As @Stéphane Chazelas mentioned in the comment, if you like to compile and install the shell from scratch, be sure to add the path in `/etc/shells`.

Change the shell using

```
chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh
```

From [man page](https://www.mankier.com/1/chsh):

> `-s, --shell SHELL` The name of the user's new login shell. Setting this field to blank causes the system to select the default login shell.

Logout and login again.

Comment: Yes, if you install the shell as part of a OS package, the OS packaging will typically add the shell to `/etc/shells`. The point here is that if you compile and install the shell by hand, you also need to add the path to `/etc/shells` yourself by hand.

Comment: Good point. I was thinking of a package manager like 'apt'. I have edited the answer to include your point.

Comment: This is essentially what the other two answers have already said, though.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Ubuntu 21 on ARM64 (Raspberry Pi 4), and there is more to this issue than the answers reveal. I installed zsh and ksh and tried changing my shell to zsh and to ksh using chsh, and both times I got the "invalid shell" message. I checked /etc/shells, and that file contained both shells. I tried the chsh command using just the bare shell names (zsh, ksh) and also using the full path names as listed in /etc/shells. I couldn't get it to work. Finally, out of frustration I just changed my shell in the /etc/passwd file, and then it worked. Later, I learned that there are two different ways of invoking chsh. What I was trying was: chsh -s  , which gave the error message. But chsh can also be invoked by simply typing chsh . This opens an interactive session:

```
$ chsh
Password: 
Changing the login shell for tom
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Login Shell [/bin/ksh93]: /usr/bin/zsh
```

When I do it this way, it works. However, entering the command as chsh -s  still doesn't work.