# echo $SHELL shows `/bin/bash` as the output even after changing the default shell to zsh

Tags: shell, zsh

I referred to this answer to change my default shell [How to change default shell to ZSH - chsh says "invalid shell"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111365/how-to-change-default-shell-to-zsh-chsh-says-invalid-shell/)

After adding zsh to `/etc/shells` and doing `sudo chsh -s "$(command -v zsh)" "${USER}"` I ran `echo $SHELL` (which gave no output btw so I thought that it must have ran successfully) and it gave me `/bin/bash`

I closed my shell and opened up a new shell session and zsh showed up so I thought it must have been fixed with a restart, after that when I ran `echo $SHELL` in the zsh session it still gave me the same output ``` /bin/bash``$SHELL --version ``` also gives me the bash version not the zsh one

everytime I do ctrl+alt+t I do get a zsh session but this `echo $SHELL` output is making me suspicious.

UPDATE: I am running Ubuntu Budgie 18.04.3 and I got `/bin/zsh` from `echo $0`

Comment: I guess, its normal behaviour. I just tried in my macos. I use bash as my default shell. So I changed my default shell to `zsh` and then `echo $SHELL` it gave me: `/usr/local/bin/bash`
I guess you will need to change your environment variable, the output you get from `printenv`

Comment: Hi, you just said that you use bash as your default and that is why it gives you bash when you `echo $SHELL` but in my case I used `chsh` to change my default (you don't mention changing your default). I don't see how your case is similar to mine?

Comment: What output you get from `echo $0` ? Could you add that in your question ?

Comment: I got `/bin/zsh` from `echo $0` @RakibFiha

Comment: Ok, just made sure that you are in `zsh` shell. What happens if you `export SHELL=/bin/zsh` ?

Comment: `su --login $USER` I did this in my current zsh session and echo $SHELL gave me zsh this time but I am gonna have to do it everytime I start a new shell session is there anyway workaround for this?

Comment: @palash25 Reboot or log out completely. Then log in again. That's your workaround. `SHELL` is only set when you log in.

Comment: that worked thanks

Comment: What this question lacks is an explanation of "opened up a new shell session".  Starting a fresh instance of a GUI terminal emulator within _the same GUI login session_ is not the same as logging off and back on again, nor is it the same as a TUI login session.  And _exactly which terminal emulator it is_ also matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `SHELL` environment variable is only set when you perform a full login, e.g. by logging out and logging in again, or by using `su - "$USER"` or `ssh "$USER@localhost"` or some other command that performs a full login.

It is usually the `login` program that sets this variable based on what the user's login shell is in the `passwd` database.  This is called as part of the login process by whatever process is accepting a login request from a user (e.g. via `sshd` or `gdm` etc.)

From the `login(1)` manual on Ubuntu:

> Your user and group ID will be set according to their values in the `/etc/passwd` file. The value for
>   `$HOME`, `$SHELL`, `$PATH`, `$LOGNAME`, and `$MAIL` are set according to the appropriate fields in the password
>   entry. Ulimit, umask and nice values may also be set according to entries in the GECOS field.

Just starting a new shell session will not set this variable's value, not even if the shell is started as a "login shell".

Answer (score 1):

Wanting to add to Kusalananda's excellent and accepted answer:

On macOS if you want to to see the change without logging out of the GUI you can enter the following in Terminal:

```
$ logout [your username]
```

Then open a new Terminal session and enter:

```
echo $SHELL
```

You will see your new environment setting.