# Cannot switch to bash from zsh

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

On a new mac, trying to switch to bash for a minute:

```bash
alex.mills@alex uta-phd %
alex.mills@alex uta-phd % echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
alex.mills@alex uta-phd %
alex.mills@alex uta-phd % exec bash

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`. 
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
%na%m %1~ %#
%na%m %1~ %# echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
%n@%m %1~ %#
```

`echo "$SHELL"` keeps saying I am using `/bin/zsh`

What to do?

Comment: Related https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/558387/414186 . You can use `su - $USER -s /bin/bash` to login with bash and load  all environment correctly. (you actually are using `bash` when run `exec bash` )

Comment: `echo "$SHELL"` doesn't tell you anything useful for purposes of this question -- `SHELL` isn't intended to represent the _current_ shell; instead, it's documented to represent it's the _user's preferred_ shell. `declare -p BASH_VERSION` if you want to conclusively know if you're in bash; ignore `SHELL`, which is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 17):

You *are* running bash. That's why the prompt looks weird. Bash and zsh both use the `PS1` variable as the main setting for the prompt, but they have different escape sequences (backslash-character in bash, percent-character in zsh, and the second characters have different meanings).

Normally the `PS1` variable should be set by the shell's initialization file (`.bashrc` or `.zshrc`) and not exported to the environment (since it only makes sense inside one given program), but many systems (including major Linux distributions) are poorly configured and export `PS1`. MacOS correctly does not export `PS1` out of the box as far as I can tell, but it seems that your own files do (or maybe a different version of macOS from the one I checked), and for some reason the system `bashrc` on macOS specifically does not change `PS1` if it's already set.

The `SHELL` environment variable does not indicate what shell you are running. It indicates what shell you *want* to run. It tells programs that want to start a shell which shell to run. Just running another shell manually does not change `$SHELL`.

If you see a shell prompt and you aren't sure what shell is running, you can check with `ps`. In all Bourne-style shells (sh, ash, bash, ksh, zsh, …), `$$` stands for the shell's process id, thus `ps $$` tells you what program the current shell is. In fish you'd get an error that makes it obvious you're running fish because `$$` is not valid there.

Comment: Usually one can also use `echo $0` to see which shell is currently running.

Comment: Mind, one generally shouldn't `export PS1`; keeping it local to the current process would prevent it from leaking across shells.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying `exec bash`?  To launch a `bash` shell, just run `bash`.  For a shell that acts as a login shell, use `bash -l`.  To permanently change your shell to `bash`, use `chsh`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you changed the shell afterwords? If not then invoke `chsh -s $(which bash)` and `echo $SHELL`.